# issues with Eclipse and references on Android projects

Tags: android, eclipse

So I opened a project, went to `Activity1.java`, changed a `boolean` value from `false` to `true` and ran. I got a null pointer exception on a TOTALLY UNRELATED class. Seems like a call to `findViewById` is returning null for some XML layout ID.

How is that even possible? this is not the first time eclipse does that. Previous times it gave some errors like "You cannot cast an ImageView to a Button.... and that's NOT what was happening, it was fixed rebooting eclipse after 15 mins.

is there any cache or something that might be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Did you clean your project?

Answer (score 1):

> How is that even possible?

I haven't run into it as a problem in quite some time, but the compiled version of your resources apparently got out of sync with the compiled versions of the Java classes referencing those resources. Project > Clean from the Eclipse main menu solves this.

Make sure you are on a relatively recent version of the ADT plugin for Eclipse (current version: R22).